# Setting field of a Message inside Message Protobuf

Tags: c++, nested, protocol-buffers

I have the following protobuf definition:

```
message CBMessage {
  
    required int32 type = 1; //defines the kind of message that we send
    optional RepoMessage repomessage = 2;
  
    message RepoMessage { 
        optional int32 nodeid = 1;
        optional int32 timestampsec = 2;
        optional int32 timestampmicrosec = 3;
    }
}
```

As you can note, the `repomessage` field is a field of the "outer" message `CBMessage`.

I would like to access `nodeid` field (of the "inner" message `RepoMessage`) in order to modify this parameter. So I create a CBMessage object:

```
CBTxMessages::CBMessage* cbmsg;
this->cbmsg = new CBTxMessages::CBMessage;
```

And I have tried to modify the `nodeid` field in this way:

```
this->cbmsg->repomessage().set_nodeid(message[0]);
```

Yet, I get the following error when I compile:

> error: pasar ‘const CBTxMessages::CBMessage_RepoMessage’ como el argumento ‘this’ de ‘void CBTxMessages::CBMessage_RepoMessage::set_nodeid(google::protobuf::int32)’ descarta a los calificadores [-fpermissive]

(The error is in Spanish but I think that you can understand). A possible translation will be:

> "the 'this' argument of 'void CBTxMessages :: CBMessage_RepoMessage :: set_nodeid (google :: protobuf :: int32)' discards the qualifiers")

I have investigated it and found that the problem is related to the fact that the "basic getter" of the `repomessage` field returns (`repomessage()`) is returned as const reference (thus it cannot be modified directly), but I do wish to modify it.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Can someone add the translation in english for non-spanish speakers?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of

```
this->cbmsg->repomessage().set_nodeid(message[0]);
```

you'll need

```
this->cbmsg->mutable_repomessage()->set_nodeid(message[0]);
```

to set the `repomessage` field directly. `repomessage()` will return a `const  CBMessage_RepoMessage&` that cannot be modified.

Answer (score 0):

In case you'd want to set all the fields at once, you can use [`set_allocated_foo()`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/cpp-generated/#embeddedmessage) along with copy or move constructors, e.g.,

```cpp
this->cbmsg->set_allocated_repomessage(new RepoMessage(repomessage));
```